# How to loop through array using $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
var latLng=[{
                "coordinates":[
                  [
                    [0,0],
                    [0.6,0.6],
                    [3,3],
                    [5.5]
                  ]
                ]
                }];
```

I need to print each set of value. which means,

```
[0,0]
[0.6,0.6]
[3,3]
[5.5]
```

Because am gonna use this values as latLng in my map to show an icon.So I tried this.

```
 $.each(latLng,function(index,value){
                    console.log(value.coordinates)
                    //L.marker(value.coordinates).addTo(map)
                })
```

Am getting like this

[image]

How can I can each set of LatLng separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @billynoah This has nothing to do with the understanding of a `.each()` loop. It's more about the understanding of a object/array structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Study the structure of `latLng`. It is an array with one element, which is an object with one field. On this field there is an array containing just another array, which in turn contains the coordinates you're looking for.

So, in order to get the desired result, you'd have to write:

```
$.each(latLng[0]['coordinates'][0], function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

You'd probably want to rethink the structure of `latLng` before you continue, though.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the following:

```
$.each(latLng[0].coordinates[0], function(index,value){
                    console.log(valuе);
                });
```

Comment: But its returning undefined.

Comment: change to console.log(value).

Comment: @laz My bad.. I've just copied the rest of your code after `$.each(latLng[0].coordinates[0]`. A good example why you should never copy code.